# ORMLite Custom Dao by inheriting from BaseDaoImpl

Tags: android, model, dns, persistence, ormlite

Typically, your domain module and persistence module are separate modules with the persistence module depending on the domain module.

if you use DatabaseTable annotation there's no way of specifying your daoClass as its in another module(persistence) which the domain has no access/dependency to. How do I overcome this problem?

Regards

Comment: Right now it is difficult to understand what you are asking.  Can you provide more details or may a small code sample?

Comment: Thanx Gray. suppose you have domain class:

Comment: Thanx Gray. the issue here is cyclic dependency. project A(the domain model) is depended on by project B(the persistence) yet in the model we need a way to specify the daoClass for the model. for example: @DatabaseTable(tableName="", daoClass=PersonDaoImpl.class) public class Person { }    this will not compile as PersonDaoImpl sits in the project B which is not referenced as B already references project A. perhaps would be better to supply another property in the DatabaseTable annotation that takes a fully qualified name of the DAO class. hope makes sense now. thanks

Comment: Oh I get it.  There is no plans to support this feature unfortunately.